# Calculating the computer memory required to estimate a fixed effects logit model

Tags: r, stata, computational-statistics

What is the calculation to determine the computer memory necessary to estimate a fixed effects logit model? Will this calculation vary across statistical software? For example, let's say I want to estimate a model with 180 fixed effects in addition to three independent variables for a dataset with 2 million observations. How would I determine the amount of memory necessary to estimate a logit model using the `glm` function in the R `stats` package? Would the answer be be different for the `logit` command in Stata?

Comment: "Would the answer be be different for the logit command in Stata?" Yes. Memory demand depends on the programming language, the specific algorithm, the specific implementation of the algorithm, the model structure, the data structure, ... If memory demand is an issue for you, you might be interested in the biglm package.

Comment: I don't really understand what "180 fixed effects in addition to three independent variables" is supposed to mean but that appears to be a model with a huge number of parameters. Usually that is not a very sensible model and you should focus on reducing the number of parameters, not the least because that many predictors can easily lead to issues with multicollinearity.

Comment: another consideration is if your effects are just dummy variables, in which case the data can be represented efficiently by sparse matrices as supported by eg glmnet.

Comment: The calculation consists of benchmarking memory usage for smaller models, fitting a reasonable function to the trend, and extrapolating.  The need for such empiricism is compelling, because it depends on details of the algorithm as well as the nature of your data and how they are represented in RAM.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. Is the function likely to be linear or exponential?

Comment: It would likely be a low degree polynomial in the number of variables, perhaps quadratic.  I would expect it to be linear in the number of observations, but sometimes that's not the case because different algorithms or RAM storage mechanisms kick in at some threshold.